# Multiple rating bars with DYRateView

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a view with 3 ratings bars on it.

How do I tell them apart in the code?  Right now if I change the top one it sees it fine but if I then change either or the other two it cannot separate them from one another.

The code is from git https://github.com/dyang/DYRateView

```
- (void)changedToNewRate:(NSNumber *)rate {
    NSString *rating = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rate: %d", rate.intValue];
    NSLog(@"rating: %@",rating);
}
```

This is where is sees the changing.

And this is the .m file

```
#import "Survey.h"

@implementation Survey

@synthesize btnSubmit;

- (void)setUpEditableRateView {
    DYRateView *rateService = [[DYRateView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 55, self.view.bounds.size.width, 40) fullStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarFullLarge@2x.png"] emptyStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarEmptyLarge@2x.png"]];
    rateService.padding = 20;
    rateService.alignment = RateViewAlignmentCenter;
    rateService.editable = YES;
    rateService.delegate =self;
    [scroller addSubview:rateService];
    [rateService release];

    DYRateView *rateFood = [[DYRateView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 130, self.view.bounds.size.width, 40) fullStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarFullLarge@2x.png"] emptyStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarEmptyLarge@2x.png"]];
    rateFood.padding = 20;
    rateFood.alignment = RateViewAlignmentCenter;
    rateFood.editable = YES;
    rateFood.delegate = self;
   [scroller addSubview:rateFood];
   [rateFood release];

  DYRateView *rateCleanliness = [[DYRateView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, self.view.bounds.size.width, 40) fullStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarFullLarge@2x.png"] emptyStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarEmptyLarge@2x.png"]];
   rateCleanliness.padding = 20;
   rateCleanliness.alignment = RateViewAlignmentCenter;
   rateCleanliness.editable = YES;
   rateCleanliness.delegate = self;
   [scroller addSubview:rateCleanliness];
   [rateCleanliness release];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return YES;
}

- (void)changedToNewRate:(NSNumber *)rate {
    NSString *rating = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rate: %d", rate.intValue];
    NSLog(@"rating: %@",rating);
}

- (IBAction)btnSubmit:(id)sender{

}

-(IBAction)mainMenu{

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];   
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 600)];
    scroller.BackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [self setUpEditableRateView];

    [btnSubmit useGreenConfirmStyle];
 }


 - (void)viewDidUnload
 {
    [super viewDidUnload];
     // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
 }

 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
     // Return YES for supported orientations
     return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }

 @end
```

**UPDATE**

ok with the new code I added an if statement

```
- (void)rateView:(DYRateView *)rateView changedToNewRate:(NSNumber *)rate {
    NSString *barName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", rateView];
    if (barName == @"rateView1") {
        NSString *bar1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rate: %d", rate.intValue];
        NSLog(@"bar 1: %@",bar1);
    }else if(barName == @"rateView2"){
        NSString *bar2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rate: %d", rate.intValue];
        NSLog(@"bar 2: %@",bar2);
    }else{
       NSLog(@"NO BAR: %@",barName);
    } 
  self.rateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rate: %d", rate.intValue];

  }
```

It works however Instead of getting back "rateView1" or 2 or 3.  I get back

```
 NO BAR: <DYRateView: 0x78229b0; frame = (0 40; 320 20); opaque = NO; layer =
 <CALayer:0x7824900>>
```

Which is correct in nature but I was hoping for the name of the rateView such as "rateView1"

**SOLUTION:**

in .h file @property your 2 or 3 bars

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) DYRateView *rateView1,*rateView2;
```

in .m @synthesize them

```
@synthesize rateView1;
@synthesize rateView2;
```

then

```
(void)setUpEditableRateView {
    rateView1 = [[DYRateView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, self.view.bounds.size.width, 20) fullStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarFullLarge.png"] emptyStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarEmptyLarge.png"]];
    rateView1.padding = 20;
    rateView1.alignment = RateViewAlignmentCenter;
    rateView1.editable = YES;
    rateView1.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:rateView1];
    [rateView1 release];

    rateView2 = [[DYRateView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.bounds.size.width, 20) fullStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarFullLarge.png"] emptyStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarEmptyLarge.png"]];
    rateView2.padding = 20;
    rateView2.alignment = RateViewAlignmentCenter;
    rateView2.editable = YES;
    rateView2.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:rateView2];
    [rateView2 release];

    // Set up a label view to display rate
    self.rateLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, self.view.bounds.size.width, 20)] autorelease];
    self.rateLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    self.rateLabel.text = @"Tap above to rate";
    [self.view addSubview:self.rateLabel];
}
```

Then Finally

```
- (void)rateView:(DYRateView *)rateView changedToNewRate:(NSNumber *)rate {

    if (rateView == rateView1) {
        NSString *bar1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rate: %d", rate.intValue];
        NSLog(@"bar 1: %@",bar1);
    }else if(rateView == rateView2){
        NSString *bar2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rate: %d", rate.intValue];
        NSLog(@"bar 2: %@",bar2);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"NO BAR: %@",rateView);
    }     
    self.rateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rate: %d", rate.intValue];   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for using DYRateView!

The current version of DYRateView doesn't support listening to multiple instances all at the same time, but that doesn't mean that we can't do that. :)

If you don't mind updating the source code, you can find a method named `notifyDelegate` in DYRateView.m, and change `[self.delegate performSelector:@selector(changedToNewRate:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.rate]]` to something like `[self.delegate performSelector:@selector(rateView:changedToNewRate:) withObject:self withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.rate]]`.  In this way you are able to pass the rateView itself as a parameter to its listener.

I haven't tried the above code yet as I don't have access to my Mac at this point, but I think this should give you an idea regarding how to achieve your goal.

Comment: i changed it to - (void)notifyDelegate {
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(rateView:changedToNewRate:)]) {
        
      [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(rateView:changedToNewRate:) withObject:self withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.rate]];
    }
 then I changed in the .m calling class changeToNewRate to : - (void)rateView:changedToNewRate:(NSNumber *)rate {
    NSString *rating = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rate: %d", rate.intValue];
    NSLog(@"rating: %@",rating);
} -- nothing happens. if I leave the changeToNewRate alone it crashes

Comment: @Rick - You'll need to change the method definition in `DYRateViewDelegate` as well.  I updated the source code on Github.  You can pull and try the latest one.

Comment: I tried this out and - (void)rateView:(DYRateView *)rateView changedToNewRate:(NSNumber *)rate {
    NSString *bar1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rate: %d", rate.intValue];
    NSLog(@"bar1: %@",bar1);
}   is picking up all three bars as "bar1"  I would think the rateView.delegate  = self; has something to do with it but I'm still learning iOS.

Comment: hahaha I got it!  Now if there is a better way let me know. And thank you for all your help.

Comment: @Rick - You'll need to override a method called `description` in `DYRateView` if you want to log in a way specific to your need. You can also try setting a `tag` to any `DYRateView` instance and compare your instances based on those tags.

Answer (score 0):

I just set the tag for each of my rateviews to tell them apart, so in your example, I add a tag to each one:

```
#define serviceTag 1
#define foodTag 2
#define cleanlinessTag 3

- (void)setUpEditableRateView {
       DYRateView *rateService = [[DYRateView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 55, self.view.bounds.size.width, 40) fullStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarFullLarge@2x.png"] emptyStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarEmptyLarge@2x.png"]];
       rateService.padding = 20;
       rateService.alignment = RateViewAlignmentCenter;
       rateService.editable = YES;
       rateService.tag = serviceTag;
       rateService.delegate =self;
       [scroller addSubview:rateService];
       [rateService release];

       DYRateView *rateFood = [[DYRateView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 130, self.view.bounds.size.width, 40) fullStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarFullLarge@2x.png"] emptyStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarEmptyLarge@2x.png"]];
       rateFood.padding = 20;
       rateFood.alignment = RateViewAlignmentCenter;
       rateFood.editable = YES;
       rateFood.tag = foodTag;
       rateFood.delegate = self;
       [scroller addSubview:rateFood];
       [rateFood release];

       DYRateView *rateCleanliness = [[DYRateView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, self.view.bounds.size.width, 40) fullStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarFullLarge@2x.png"] emptyStar:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StarEmptyLarge@2x.png"]];
       rateCleanliness.padding = 20;
       rateCleanliness.alignment = RateViewAlignmentCenter;
       rateCleanliness.editable = YES;
       rateCleanliness.delegate = self;
       rateCleanliness.tag = cleanlinessTag;
       [scroller addSubview:rateCleanliness];
       [rateCleanliness release];
    }
```

Then, in the delegate method, you can just check the tag:

```
- (void)rateView:(DYRateView *)rateView changedToNewRate:(NSNumber *)rate {
    switch (rateView.tag) {
        case foodTag:
           // Do something for food
           break;
        case serviceTag:
           // Do something for service
           break;
        case cleanlinessTag:
           // Do something for cleanliness
           break;
        default:
           break;
    }

  }
```